# Android Room database Response with data from two different tables

Tags: android, sql, pojo, android-room

So I have two tables City and Street I wrote query to return City and its streets with one query response looks like this

```
1 City1

1 Street1
2 Street2
3 Street3
```

and I have POJO class for this response:

```
data class CityResponse(var city: City, var streets: List<Street>)
```

But I can't compile because it throws error:

```
error: Cannot figure out how to read this field from cursor private java.util.List<Street> streets
```

How can I write this response data class that room would understand what do I mean with variable `streets: List<Street>`

Answer (score 0):

In this case used joins query and make one common pojo class that give both details.  then make query like below ..

```
    @Query("SELECT * FROM Student s LEFT JOIN BookIssue b ON s.StudentId =b.StudentId")
List<JoinData> getJoinData();
```

you can also implement inner join and others joins but make one single pojo that give both table record.

and also one more way first find city and make for loop and find based on city name into street and getting street data.

Comment: I have similar query, but my problem is that it complains about this join pojo class which has to hold city and list of streets

Comment: there for make one single pojo class that define city and street fields. other wise you make single single query and manage according to for loop.